# How to put buttons sticked to borders?

Tags: java, swing

I mean with the standard flow layout I get this:

[image]

But I need something like this instead

[image]

Is there a way to put buttons like this in `JPanel`? Which layout should I choose?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Use `BoxLayout` and add `Box.createHorizontalGlue()` in between 2 buttons.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
panel.add(new JButton("Left"));
panel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
panel.add(new JButton("Mid"));
panel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
panel.add(new JButton("Right"));
```